# How to update the existing identity into hyperledger CA using fabric node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to implement various feature which is mention on https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#dynamically-updating-identities

however I am got confused when I saw in fabric node sdk identity service class https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/IdentityService.html#update__anchor

In this class mention some function like update which is used for update the idendtity, however how to implement it not shown into this.

Could anyone has done some work on identity service on HLF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the doc quite well explained. The doc tells you it is using `FabricCAClient` (https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/FabricCAClient.html#newIdentityService__anchor), it describes the function (https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/IdentityService.html#update__anchor) and the parameters (https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/global.html#IdentityRequest). Just update the identity as a registrar and enroll it later as the final user.

An example (with `create` instead of `update`, but it is almost the same): https://books.google.es/books?id=UMzaDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&hl=es&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false